# Multi button GUI VBSscript

Tags: user-interface, input, menu, vbscript, messagebox

Does any one know how I could make a 16 button all in two side by side vertical row GUI. Each button will set a variable called menuoutput to a value like 1 for the first button 2 for the second ECT. I have been testing this code but I don't see if there is a way to add 16 buttons to it.

```
x=msgbox("Do you want to start" ,4, "Program")
If x = 6 Then
Wscript.Echo "yes"
Else
Wscript.Echo "no"
End If
```

Comment: Its not possible to show all buttons at once in `MsgBox`. You might try this with a custom userform.

Comment: Are you using VBA or pure VBScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript don't support GUI creation natively. You can either go the HTA way (as illustrated by Ekkehard.Horner above or you can go hybrid way to do this. In my example, I used shell script to achieve it.

1- Create Test.ps1 script with following code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Testing Custom MessageBox"
$Form.Width = 350
$Form.Height = 100
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Font = $Font

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Text = "Custom MsgBox!"
$Label.AutoSize = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($Label)

$Button1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(5,25)
$Button1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$Button1.Text = "Button1"
$Button1.Add_Click({Write-Host "Button1 was pressed";$Form.Close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button1)
$Button2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(85,25)
$Button2.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$Button2.Text = "Button2"
$Button2.Add_Click({Write-Host "Button2 was pressed";$Form.Close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button2)
$Button3 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button3.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(165,25)
$Button3.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$Button3.Text = "Button3"
$Button3.Add_Click({Write-Host "Button3 was pressed";$Form.Close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button3)
$Button4 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button4.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(245,25)
$Button4.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$Button4.Text = "Button4"
$Button4.Add_Click({Write-Host "Button4 was pressed";$Form.Close()})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button4)

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
Exit 0
```

2- Call this in your vbscript file - Test.vbs

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set exec = objShell.Exec("powershell -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -file C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\Test.ps1")
exec.StdIn.Close()
WScript.Echo exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
Set exec = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit 0
```

So when the script is called you would be able to see the message box
[image]

And when you press any of the button, you would get the corresponding message
[image]

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I cant get it to work I get the black power shell window and then a small blank box with only and ok button

Comment: Hmm ... works for me though ... I've just added the screenshots. Have you modified the code? Can you post the modified code please?

Comment: I haven't modified it yet I am using the original

Comment: This might sound stupid but did you changed the filepath name of your p21 file? `Set exec = objShell.Exec("powershell -executionpolicy bypass -noninteractive -file C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\Test.ps1")`

Answer (score 4):

The 'natural' way to add a GUI to VBScript is to write an .[HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application). To get you started:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <Title>menubuttons</Title>
  <hta:application id="menubuttons" scroll = "no">
  <script type="text/vbscript">
   Function window_onload
     Dim spMenu : Set spMenu = document.getElementById("spMenu")
     Dim nB
     For nB = 1 To 5
         Dim oB : Set oB = document.createElement("input")
         oB.setAttribute "type", "button"
         oB.id    = "B" & nB
         oB.value = oB.id
         Set oB.onclick = GetRef("menu")
         spMenu.appendChild oB
     Next
   End Function
   Function menu
     MsgBox Me.id, vbOKOnly, "menu selection"
   End Function
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span id = "spMenu"></span>
  <hr />
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: 'output']

To learn about the DOM, start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Microsoft provides a quite extensive [tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) on HTA.

Comment: Great, I tried it and it works even in 2021 with Windows 10, also I integrated it with Bootstrap 4.6 and it works correctly adding these lines in the head
   <hta: application id = "" applicationname = "HTML Applications" border = "none" caption = "no" contextmenu = "no" icon = "" navigable = "yes" scroll = "no" showintaskbar = "no" singleinstance = "no" sysmenu = "no" version = "1.0">
     <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
     <meta charset = "utf-8">
     <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">